# How to download Visual Studio 2015 Community as a torrent file?

Tags: visual-studio, torrent

For the sole reason that the Internet bandwidth is too weak, I could never download such a large file as Visual Studio, and I need it. Is there a way to torrent the IDE?

Answer (score 2):

I used BurnBit to make a .TORRENT file by providing the direct link to the website.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywziitMRstSVExHNmZTVXAxVG8

Zero everything for now (no seeds, no leechers). It downloads but not with the speed of a torrent with loads of seeders.

I just wanted to download it like in torrent cause, bad internet (PH). So, definitely need some patience.